# is it necessary to first login to sandbox account while making payment using paypal standard

Tags: paypal

is it necessary to first login to sandbox account and without closing the browser we have to purchase and pay while using paypal standard ipn in asp.net

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, yes. You log into the sandbox with your developer account, and then when you land on PayPal from your site you log in again with your test account, which exists only within the developer account.

Or if you want to test making a payment by credit card without being logged in, you still have to be logged in with your developer account. And you have to be logged in with the developer account *before* you land on the PayPal site.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found that if you try to switch between different (real) paypal accounts, you will no longer be able to get into the sandbox site at all... it just keeps taking you to the live site.
This appears to be an issue with cookies. 
In any rate, I got around it by using a different browser for the second account.